# Python: truncate txt file before writing

Tags: python, truncate, file-writing

I have a set of .txt files (12) that I want to read and write to 3 output .txt files (so each output will have text from all 12 files).

I accomplish this with the following code, BUT the files do not overwrite what is already there, but append the text. I realize this may be due to me using "a" as append, but if I use "w", only the first document of my 12 gets written to each output.

The "truncate()" method seems to have no effect.

```
def WriteFiles():
# import library
import glob

# read file names
txt_files = glob.glob('input/*.txt')
output_files = glob.glob('output*')

# loop trough outputs & files and append
for index_out, output in enumerate(output_files):
    for index_in, file in enumerate(txt_files):
        with open(file, 'r+') as f, open(output, 'a') as o:
            print('Writing input {} to output {}'.format(index_in, index_out))
            o.truncate()
            o.write(f.read())
```

Comment: I think you're almost there. But after the `f.read()` is performed, an `f.seek(0)` or the like has to be done after so that you are writing at the beginning of the file again.

Comment: AFAI understand, the OPs problem is with the output not the input. Anyway the example code only performs 1 read for each `open` of the input files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply `open` the output file earlier, in the first `for` loop. E.g.

```
for index_out, output in enumerate(output_files):
    with open(output, 'w') as o:
        for index_in, file in enumerate(txt_files):
            with open(file, 'r+') as f:
                print('Writing input {} to output {}'.format(index_in, index_out))
                o.write(f.read())
```

This will only open and truncate each output file once, before the second `for` loop starts, and the `file` object will look after the current position in the output file.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I tried to open the file earlier in the loop but I put it at a different place in the loop and it did not work.